# Stop Jquery nth-child affecting sub-children

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Please see my code below. This is a simplified version of a problem I am facing: I want to insert some text after the second paragraph, but NOT in the blockquote. At present my jquery is making my new text appear after the 2nd paragraph in content AND the 2nd paragraph in the blockquote.

I am aware with how nth-child works, but have not been able to find a method to limit how far it goes.

Thanks.

```
<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <blockquote>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </blockquote>
</div>

<script>
$( "<p><strong>I AM NEW TEXT</strong></p>" ).insertAfter( ".content p:nth-child(2)" );
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace it with child selector:

```
$( "<p><strong>I AM NEW TEXT</strong></p>" ).insertAfter( ".content > p:nth-child(2)" );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it along with [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) to select only the direct child

`.content p:nth-child(2)` uses descendant relationship so it will match all the 2nd child element inside the `.content` element(at all levels)

```js
$("<p><strong>I AM NEW TEXT</strong></p>").insertAfter(".content  > p:nth-child(2)");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <blockquote>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```